# SMART HDD Status Output Interpretation - Help appreciated

Tags: hard-drive

Here is a disk with some strange mounting errors on an ubuntu system. I'm not sure, if it is due to false settings in the fstab or an actual hardware error. I run smartctl to check the status of the disk.
I don't have any experience in reading the results, but for me it looks like there are severe problems with that disk.
But the guys in the shop where the disk has been bought said, the disk is fine.
Anyone with some spare time to give me hints about the actual state of the disk and how significant the SMART results are?

```
smartctl 6.5 2016-01-24 r4214 [x86_64-linux-4.4.0-22-generic] (local 

build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Toshiba 3.5" DT01ABA... Desktop HDD
Device Model:     TOSHIBA DT01ABA300
Serial Number:    XXXXXXXXXXXXX
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000039 ff4c8910e
Firmware Version: MZ6OABB0
User Capacity:    3.000.592.982.016 bytes [3,00 TB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5940 rpm
Form Factor:      3.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 3.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Thu Jun  2 15:48:48 2016 CEST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: FAILED!
Drive failure expected in less than 24 hours. SAVE ALL DATA.
See vendor-specific Attribute list for failed Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x84) Offline data collection activity
                    was suspended by an interrupting command from host.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 121) The previous self-test completed having
                    the read element of the test failed.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (28357) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x5b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 473) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000b   078   078   016    Pre-fail  Always       -       61472768
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0005   142   142   054    Pre-fail  Offline      -       90
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0007   146   146   024    Pre-fail  Always       -       390 (Average 362)
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       281
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   001   001   005    Pre-fail  Always   FAILING_NOW 642
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000b   100   100   067    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0005   138   138   020    Pre-fail  Offline      -       33
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       291
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   060    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       274
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       375
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       375
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   181   181   000    Old_age   Always       -       33 (Min/Max 17/53)
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   074   074   000    Old_age   Always       -       648
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0022   001   001   000    Old_age   Always       -       25960
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0008   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       66
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x000a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
ATA Error Count: 8252 (device log contains only the most recent five errors)
    CR = Command Register [HEX]
    FR = Features Register [HEX]
    SC = Sector Count Register [HEX]
    SN = Sector Number Register [HEX]
    CL = Cylinder Low Register [HEX]
    CH = Cylinder High Register [HEX]
    DH = Device/Head Register [HEX]
    DC = Device Command Register [HEX]
    ER = Error register [HEX]
    ST = Status register [HEX]
Powered_Up_Time is measured from power on, and printed as
DDd+hh:mm:SS.sss where DD=days, hh=hours, mm=minutes,
SS=sec, and sss=millisec. It "wraps" after 49.710 days.

Error 8252 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 146 hours (6 days + 2 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 e8 1c aa 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x00aa1ce8 = 11148520

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 03 08 e8 1c aa e0 00   3d+05:57:06.926  READ DMA EXT
  25 03 08 e8 1c aa e0 00   3d+05:57:02.420  READ DMA EXT
  25 03 08 e8 1c aa e0 00   3d+05:56:57.914  READ DMA EXT
  25 03 08 e8 1c aa e0 00   3d+05:56:53.407  READ DMA EXT
  25 03 08 e8 1c aa e0 00   3d+05:56:48.901  READ DMA EXT

Error 8251 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 146 hours (6 days + 2 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 e8 1c aa 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x00aa1ce8 = 11148520

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 03 08 e8 1c aa e0 00   3d+05:57:02.420  READ DMA EXT
  25 03 08 e8 1c aa e0 00   3d+05:56:57.914  READ DMA EXT
  25 03 08 e8 1c aa e0 00   3d+05:56:53.407  READ DMA EXT
  25 03 08 e8 1c aa e0 00   3d+05:56:48.901  READ DMA EXT
  25 03 08 e8 1c aa e0 00   3d+05:56:44.397  READ DMA EXT

Error 8250 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 146 hours (6 days + 2 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 e8 1c aa 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x00aa1ce8 = 11148520

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 03 08 e8 1c aa e0 00   3d+05:56:57.914  READ DMA EXT
  25 03 08 e8 1c aa e0 00   3d+05:56:53.407  READ DMA EXT
  25 03 08 e8 1c aa e0 00   3d+05:56:48.901  READ DMA EXT
  25 03 08 e8 1c aa e0 00   3d+05:56:44.397  READ DMA EXT
  25 03 08 e8 1c aa e0 00   3d+05:56:39.897  READ DMA EXT

Error 8249 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 146 hours (6 days + 2 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 e8 1c aa 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x00aa1ce8 = 11148520

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 03 08 e8 1c aa e0 00   3d+05:56:53.407  READ DMA EXT
  25 03 08 e8 1c aa e0 00   3d+05:56:48.901  READ DMA EXT
  25 03 08 e8 1c aa e0 00   3d+05:56:44.397  READ DMA EXT
  25 03 08 e8 1c aa e0 00   3d+05:56:39.897  READ DMA EXT
  25 03 08 e8 1c aa e0 00   3d+05:56:35.386  READ DMA EXT

Error 8248 occurred at disk power-on lifetime: 146 hours (6 days + 2 hours)
  When the command that caused the error occurred, the device was active or idle.

  After command completion occurred, registers were:
  ER ST SC SN CL CH DH
  -- -- -- -- -- -- --
  40 51 08 e8 1c aa 00  Error: UNC 8 sectors at LBA = 0x00aa1ce8 = 11148520

  Commands leading to the command that caused the error were:
  CR FR SC SN CL CH DH DC   Powered_Up_Time  Command/Feature_Name
  -- -- -- -- -- -- -- --  ----------------  --------------------
  25 03 08 e8 1c aa e0 00   3d+05:56:48.901  READ DMA EXT
  25 03 08 e8 1c aa e0 00   3d+05:56:44.397  READ DMA EXT
  25 03 08 e8 1c aa e0 00   3d+05:56:39.897  READ DMA EXT
  25 03 08 e8 1c aa e0 00   3d+05:56:35.386  READ DMA EXT
  25 03 08 e8 1c aa e0 00   3d+05:56:30.880  READ DMA EXT

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%       271         91251656
# 2  Extended offline    Aborted by host               90%       271         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: Do you have the data on the disk backed up?

Comment: Yes, I do have a full backup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter values are normalized to 100, lower is worse, and if it's below the indicated threshold it is flagged as failing.

You have a significant raw read error rate, and the harddisk has already reallocated all spare blocks it has for this purpose.

So the disk is failing, for whatever reason. You still may be able to read everything (maybe that's what the guy in the shop has tested), but possibly not for long.

Make a backup ASAP, before it is too late, and get a new disk.

**Edit**

For the backup, make sure to mount the drive read-only. The superblock is marked during mount, and if the drive can't write it, and tries to allocate it, and doesn't have any spares to allocate anymore, there is a problem - which may give you the "strange mounting errors" you mentioned.

(Yes, I read you have already made a backup, but someone else may be reading this in the future).

Comment: Thank you for your opinion. I already backed everything up. I'm trying to get some ideas how to convince the manufacturer that it's a warranty case.

Comment: I have a question: Apparently not all values are normalized since they are over 100. Now, if a value is i.e. 50, how can one know if it's a normalized value or not? Another question: Where can one see if all spare blocks are already reallocated?

Comment: @nixda: The values are normalized to 100 in such a way that 100 is considered "totally acceptable, normal operation". Which means some values may start out over 100, and even if they degrade, they are still fine as long as they are above 100. For example, if the drive spins up a lot faster than the defined "normal operation", that's totally ok. If the temperature is a lot lower than average operating temperature, that's also ok. Etc.

Comment: @nixda: The "reallocated sector count" is at 1, which means the spare sectors are exhausted (or very near to exhaustion). That would also explain mounting errors: The superblock is marked during mount, and if the drive can't write the superblock, and tries to allocate a spare for it, and doesn't have any spares anymore, you'll get an error.

Comment: @Arothron: I suppose the SMART values should make it clear it's a warranty case - but of course all manufacturers like to avoid warrantie cases. Maybe ask the guy in the shop to write a few files onto it, in your presence? If he's a Windows guy, reformatting the drive for Windows, and then writing some stuff should also work.